# Webpack build failed when a file imported some files which are not under current working directory

Tags: webpack, ecmascript-6, redux, es6-module-loader

APP
      +---commonModule
      |    +---reducers
      |    |      +---        **gradeReducer.js**
      +---myApp
      |    +---reducers
      |    |      +---**reducers.js**
      |    +---components
      |    +---actions
      |    +---containers
      |    +---webpack.config.js

Based on above structure, I tried to import **gradeReducer.js** in       **reducers.js**. But my webpack can't build it. It  says

> "ReferenceError: Unknown plugin "transform-runtime" specified in "base" at 0"

If I put the **gradeReducer.js** under **myApp/reducers** directory, webpack can build it successfully.

Comment: What is your Babel config, where is `node_modules` and have you installed `babel-plugin-transform-runtime`?

Comment: What version of webpack are you running?